# Automatically register number into Kovan test net with signed transaction (Infura API + NodeJS)

Tags: web3js, nodejs, ethereumjs, ethereumjs-tx, sendsignedtransaction

I have a very simple Smart Contract deployed using remix.ethereum which is:

```
pragma solidity ^ 0.6.0;

contract primerContrato {

uint storeddata;

function set(uint x) public{
    storeddata = x;
}

function get() public view returns (uint){
    return storeddata;
}

}
```

I'm using Metamask to test set function, and it works properly. I can see on Etherscan my transaction hash and the input I entered on Remix.

I want to do this automatically, without having to accept transactions on Metamask. I'm using NodeJS to generate files and I want to store them hashes into the testnet blockchain. So I would be waiting for files to be generated, and calling set function of my Smart Contract to store that value. For this first test it would be a single call with a single value to store.

I've been reading a bit about signed transactions, and I've tried this code from https://medium.com/coinmonks/ethereum-tutorial-sending-transaction-via-nodejs-backend-7b623b885707
Which I changed because I don't need a web process to execute it:

```
const web3 = require('web3');
const express = require('express');
const Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction;


//Infura HttpProvider Endpoint
web3js = new web3(new web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://kovan.infura.io/v3/APIKEY")); //there goes my API

enviar();

function enviar (req,res){

        var myAddress = '0x68d9...'; //from Metamask
        var privateKey = Buffer.from('42AE...', 'hex') //from Metamask
        var toAddress ; //no address as I am posting it to the smart contract

        //contract abi is the array that you can get from the ethereum wallet or etherscan
        var contractABI =[
                            {
                                "inputs": [],
                                "name": "get",
                                "outputs": [
                                    {
                                        "internalType": "uint256",
                                        "name": "",
                                        "type": "uint256"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "stateMutability": "view",
                                "type": "function"
                            },
                            {
                                "inputs": [
                                    {
                                        "internalType": "uint256",
                                        "name": "x",
                                        "type": "uint256"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "name": "set",
                                "outputs": [],
                                "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
                                "type": "function"
                            }
                        ];
        var contractAddress ="0xb031..."; //my contract address
        //creating contract object
        var contract = new web3js.eth.Contract(contractABI,contractAddress);

        var count;
        // get transaction count, later will used as nonce
        web3js.eth.getTransactionCount(myAddress).then(function(v){
            console.log("Count: "+v);
            count = v;
            var amount = web3js.utils.toHex(1e16);
            //creating raw tranaction
            var rawTransaction = {"from":myAddress, "gasPrice":web3js.utils.toHex(60* 1e9),"gasLimit":web3js.utils.toHex(3000000),"to":contractAddress,"value":"0x0","data":contract.methods.set(0x849787ab...).encodeABI(),"nonce":web3js.utils.toHex(count+2)}
            console.log(rawTransaction);
            //creating tranaction via ethereumjs-tx
            var transaction = new Tx (rawTransaction);
            //signing transaction with private key
            transaction.sign(privateKey);
            //sending transacton via web3js module
            web3js.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x'+transaction.serialize().toString('hex'))
            .on('transactionHash',console.log);  

        })
    };
```

I've found two errors:

1st. When I try to send a 256 bit integer (uint) on `contract.methods.set(0x849787ab...)`, console throw an overflow error (1e77)

2nd. If I change this value to a smaller one, it actually shows a transaction hash, but I does not charge anything on my wallet and I doesn't appear on etherscan consequently.

Is there a simpler method to do so? Do you have any doubts?

Thank you in advance! I'm in a hurry to send this project and I would appreciate your help a lot!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I try to send a 256 bit integer (uint) on `contract.methods.set(0x849787ab...)`, console throw an overflow error (1e77)

In Javascript, `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` is equal to 2 ^ 53 - 1.

Therefore, always use strings: `contract.methods.set("0x849787ab...")`.

---

> Is there a simpler method to do so?

Here is what I use (tested with web3.js v1.2.1):

```
const Web3 = require("web3");

const YOUR_NODE_ADDRESS = "...";
const YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY  = "...";
const YOUR_INPUT_VALUE  = "...";
const YOUR_GAS_PRICE    = "...";

async function send(web3, account, gasPrice, transaction, value = 0) {
    const options = {
        to      : transaction._parent._address,
        data    : transaction.encodeABI(),
        gas     : await transaction.estimateGas({from: account.address, value: value}),
        gasPrice: gasPrice,
        value   : value
    };
    const signed  = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(options, account.privateKey);
    const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signed.rawTransaction);
    return receipt;
}

async function run() {
    const web3 = new Web3(YOUR_NODE_ADDRESS);
    const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI,contractAddress);
    const account = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY);
    const transaction = contract.methods.set(YOUR_INPUT_VALUE);
    const receipt = await send(web3, account, YOUR_GAS_PRICE, transaction);
    console.log(receipt);
}

run();
```

Comment: my node address is the one I obtain from Infura? Where does my contract hash go? and abi? Or it automatically retrieves it?

Comment: @salgarji: You seem to already have that part (initializing the web3 instance and the contract instance) in your code. So you probably don't need to take that from my answer.

Comment: I would just use `"https://kovan.infura.io/v3/APIKEY"`, BTW (i.e., no need to wrap it with `new web3.providers.HttpProvider` as far as I'm aware of).

Comment: I have this in return: 

`(node:1025) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Returned error: Transaction gas price supplied is too low. There is another transaction with same nonce in the queue. Try increasing the gas price or incrementing the nonce.`

I don't know how to increase nonce. My gas limit is over 60.000.000.000 in Kovan test net. Is not enough?

Comment: @salgarji: That's when you try to execute many transactions. In that case, you should control the nonce and increment it properly (by adding it in the `options` object above).

Comment: I'm thinking that I am maybe doing something wrong. Do I have to deploy my smart contract using Injected Web3 environment? Using my metamask wallet and keths. Or Web3 provider with my Infure link? I am a little bit lost.

Comment: THANK YOU! it worked
I only had to add         `nonce : web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account.address),`
inside options

Comment: BTW, do you think adding a value every ~4 seconds would be feasible? Or will it return an error? Will nonces be the same if there's not enough time between blocks? Should I try to send one value every 8 seconds (two values) / 16 seconds (four values) instead? I need to store 1 value every 4 seconds.

Comment: @salgarji: From my experience, it often comes down to errors once you start sending too many transactions too fast. You could technically store a batch of function-calls in the constructor of a contract, and then, deploying that contract would achieve your purpose of storing multiple values within in a single transaction.

Comment: @salgarji: NP, but please post it as a separate question, with ALL the relevant details (and ONLY the relevant details).